Block access to Wordpress website in Incognito Mode
I am trying to block access to my WordPress website when users browse in incognito or private mode. My goal is to completely prevent users in incognito mode from viewing any part of the site
I tried adding these codes in FUnctions.php to prevent the users to access the website totally!

function block_incognito_mode() {
    ?>
    <script>
        // Detect incognito mode
        function detectIncognito(callback) {
            const fs = window.RequestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
            if (!fs) {
                callback(false);
            } else {
                fs(window.TEMPORARY, 100, () => callback(false), () => callback(true));
            }
        }

        detectIncognito(function(isIncognito) {
            if (isIncognito) {
                // Block access by replacing the entire document
                document.head.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the head section
                document.body.innerHTML = `
                    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 50px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
                        <h1 style="color: #333;">Access Denied</h1>
                        <p style="color: #555;">Incognito mode is not allowed on this website.</p>
                        <p style="color: #999;">Please disable Incognito mode and refresh the page to continue.</p>
                    </div>`;
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#f2f2f2';
                document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; // Disable all interactions
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'block_incognito_mode');



Why do you want to do this? I ask because there probably does not exist a full-proof solution that can't be circumvented, but if there's a deeper problem you're trying to solve, maybe we can point you in the right direction.

There is no bullet proof solution, but there is this JS library you can use and test.
https://github.com/Joe12387/detectIncognito
From the server side i dont think you can check any thing to know if its in incognito mode.
